# Spray.io unmarshaller for `application/atom+xml`

Tags: spray, spray-client

I'm having trouble writing an unmarshaller for an atom+xml feed. The feed is just XML, so I was hoping to be able to rely on the `NodeSeqUnmarshaller`, but that unmarshaller has content range (`text/xml`, `application/xml`, `text/html`, `application/xhtml+xml`) - i.e. `application/atom+xml` is not included in the list.

On the basis of @jrudolph's comment below, I attempted to solve the problem using Unmarshaller.delegate, like this:

```
implicit val atomUnmarshaller = 
    Unmarshaller.delegate[NodeSeq, NodeSeq]('application/atom+xml')(identity)

val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[NodeSeq] = (
    sendReceive 
    ~> unmarshal[NodeSeq]
)

val response: Future[NodeSeq] = pipeline(request)
```

I'm seeing this exception message at runtime:

```
spray.httpx.PipelineException: UnsupportedContentType(Expected 'text/xml' or 
    'application/xml' or 'text/html' or 'application/xhtml+xml')
```

So, I'm stuck, and I'd be very grateful for any help that you might be able to render. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, try `Unmarshaller.delegate[NodeSeq, NodeSeq](`application/atom+xml`)(identity)`.

Comment: Try passing in the unmarshaller directly with `unmarshal(atomUnmarshaller)`.